# Using slf4j with code calling log12 code - what about the logging backend?

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

My standalone Java program should log with slf4j.

Some of dependencies log with log4j in version 1.x.

I understand that I must probably put exclusions on log4j for those dependencies and in turn add the `log4j-over-slf4j` dependency to my project?

But what about the logging backend then? Can I still use log4j in version 2 as backend for slf4j? Or will this lead to an endless logging loop?

Comment: Did you actually try? It should work just fine, but I would make sure the exclusions are correct by trying to reference log4j 1.x directly from my own code to make sure it's going through slf4j.

Comment: @E-Riz You are right, with correct exclusions it works just fine.